# How to redirect to two sites in order in HTML?

Tags: html, redirect, sites

I need to have a HTML file. When user clicks on it, it will open a site, say, example1.com and stay there for 2 seconds, then it will redirect to another site, say, example2.com. How can I achieve it?

I do some search and try the following way. It doesn't work. Can somebody help? Thank you very much.

Edited: The reason behind it is, user has to visit the first site to get cookie and then open the second site. Ideally, user should not see the first site. If HTML can't do that, what would be a good way to achieve that? I don't have access to server of either site.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A web page that loads two sites in order</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=https://www.example1.com">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=https://www.example2.com">
</head>
<body>
Please wait...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one way to achieve is using iframe

Comment: If you have access to both sites, have a meta refresh or script in each of them

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this? I bet there is a way to achieve the desired result with fewer than two redirects.

Comment: If html can't do that, what would be a good way to do that? I try to use DOS batch file, but the two links will be opened in different browsers. It doesn't work

Comment: The reason to open the two sites in order is, I have to get cookie from first site and visit the second one. So they have to be in same browser. I don't have access to any of the sites.

Comment: Naga, could you please explain a bit more, how to achieve it using iframe? Thanks